# Piping a Python script in order for it to be compared to another text file

Tags: python, unix, diff, piping

I had a simple question: I have a python script that generates a list of strings and what I want it to be able to pipe this output so that it can be compared to an existing text file in this form:

python myscript.py | diff test.txt -

The test.txt file in this case is just a text file that contains the words that are on a new line each. How would I got about doing this.

Comment: `sys.stdout.write` ?

Comment: Did you try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All text displayed by `print()` or `sys.stdout.write()` (which is used by `print()` too) will be piped to other command.

If you want to get data from other pipe like

```
ls | python myscript.py

python myscript.py < data.txt
```

then use `input()` or `sys.stdin.read()`